# App force closing while trying to integrate Stripe

Tags: java, android, stripe-payments

I am trying to integrate Stripe to process payment in my Android application.

I have the user input credit card information and then all I'm trying to do for now is create a token.  But when I click the button the app force closes.

This is not how the final app will accept cards and work with Stripe but I'm just trying to get an understanding how I will integrate Stripe in the future

```
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.ImageButton;
import android.widget.Spinner;
import android.widget.Toast;

import com.stripe.android.*;
import com.stripe.android.model.Card;
import com.stripe.android.model.Token;
import com.stripe.android.Stripe;

import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.Map;

public class newUser extends AppCompatActivity {

String fname;
String lname;
String email;
String phonenum;
String pin;
String cardNumber;
String cardCVC;
Integer cardExpMonth;
Integer cardExpYear;
String stripetok;
Card cardNew;

private static final String PUBLISHABLE_KEY = "pk_test_iUVdhdvJuurqSxIlXpzq32LS";
UserDBHelper newUserr;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_new_user);

    newUserr = new UserDBHelper(newUser.this);

    EditText fNameh = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.fNameNew);
    EditText lNameh = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.lNameNew);
    EditText emailh = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.emailNew);
    EditText phoneNumh = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.phoneNew);
    EditText pinh = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.pinNew);
    EditText cardNumberh = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.cardNumNew);
    EditText cardCVCh = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.cvcNew);
    Spinner cardExpMonthh = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.monthNew);
    Spinner cardExpYearh = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.yearNew);

    fname = fNameh.getText().toString();
    lname = lNameh.getText().toString();
    email = emailh.getText().toString();
    phonenum = phoneNumh.getText().toString();
    pin = pinh.getText().toString();
    cardNumber = cardNumberh.getText().toString();
    cardCVC = cardCVCh.getText().toString();
    cardExpMonth = (Integer) cardExpMonthh.getSelectedItem();
    cardExpYear = (Integer) cardExpYearh.getSelectedItem();


    cardNew = new Card(
            cardNumber,
            cardExpMonth,
            cardExpYear,
            cardCVC
    );

    ImageButton createNewUser = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.createNew);



    createNewUser.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v)
        {
            if(cardNew.validateCard() & cardNew.validateCVC()) {
                Stripe stripe = new Stripe();
                stripe.createToken(cardNew, PUBLISHABLE_KEY, new TokenCallback() {
                    public void onSuccess(Token token) {
                        // TODO: Send Token information to your backend to initiate a charge
                        Toast.makeText(
                                getApplicationContext(),
                                "Token created: " + token.getId(),
                                Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                    }

                    public void onError(Exception error) {
                        Log.d("Stripe", error.getLocalizedMessage());
                    }
                });

            }

            else{
                Toast.makeText(
                        getApplicationContext(),
                        "Token not made!",
                        Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }

        }
    });
```

Any ideas on why this is occuring?  I am not getting any errors but the activity won't even load.

I have included

```
compile 'com.stripe:stripe-android:2.0.2'
```

into the app's build.gradle under dependencies

Thanks for any input!

**Edit 1:**
I believe the issue may be when I'm casting a String to an Integer from the spinner.

```
E/dalvikvm: Could not find class 'android.widget.ThemedSpinnerAdapter', referenced from method android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatSpinner$DropDownAdapter.<init>
W/dalvikvm: VFY: unable to resolve instanceof 2583 (Landroid/widget/ThemedSpinnerAdapter;) in Landroid/support/v7/widget/AppCompatSpinner$DropDownAdapter;
D/dalvikvm: VFY: replacing opcode 0x20 at 0x0016
D/AndroidRuntime: Shutting down VM
W/dalvikvm: threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x416fcbc0)
E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
                  Process: com.zeuspwr.zeuspower, PID: 32121
                  java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.zeuspwr.zeuspower/com.zeuspwr.zeuspower.newUser}: java.lang.ClassCastException: java.lang.String cannot be cast to java.lang.Integer
                      at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2429)
                      at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2493)
                      at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:166)
                      at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1283)
                      at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
                      at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:136)
                      at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5584)
                      at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
                      at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
                      at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1268)
                      at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1084)
                      at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
                   Caused by: java.lang.ClassCastException: java.lang.String cannot be cast to java.lang.Integer
                      at com.zeuspwr.zeuspower.newUser.onCreate(newUser.java:62)
                      at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5447)
                      at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1094)
                      at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2393)
                      at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2493) 
                      at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:166) 
                      at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1283) 
                      at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102) 
                      at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:136) 
                      at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5584) 
                      at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method) 
                      at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515) 
                      at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1268) 
                      at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1084) 
                      at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method) 
I/Process: Sending signal. PID: 32121 SIG: 9
Application terminated.
```

Comment: provide the crash log

Comment: Also you are getting the values from text fields in the oncreate. which will be empty or null I assume on start. Get them inside the button click

Comment: Post your error log.

Comment: Sorry there it is.

Comment: java.lang.ClassCastException: java.lang.String cannot be cast to java.lang.Integer at com.zeuspwr.zeuspower.newUser.onCreate(newUser.java:62)

Comment: if a string holds an integer, you can convert it with Integer.valueOf(String)

Comment: Farooq Arshed, I just moved text fields inside button push.  Thanks haha silly error!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change

```
cardExpMonth = (Integer) cardExpMonthh.getSelectedItem();
cardExpYear = (Integer) cardExpYearh.getSelectedItem();
```

To

```
cardExpMonth = Integer.valueOf(cardExpMonthh.getSelectedItem());
cardExpYear = Integer.valueOf(cardExpYearh.getSelectedItem());
```